# Overloading the stream insertion (<<) operator?

Tags: c++

When we overload the stream insertion operator to work on user defined objects, we usually define it as a global friend function as follows:

```
ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const MyClass& x) {
    // Do something
    return out;
}
```

My question is, I believe the object `cout` (which is a global object) is passed as the first argument to this function. But, why? It's a global function, so it is accessible in this function anyway, why pass it as an argument. In other words, why not do the following:

```
ostream& operator << (const MyClass& x) {
    // Do something
    return cout;
}
```

Comment: What are you talking about? `std::ifstream f("out.txt"); f << my_object;`

Comment: (`std::ofstream`, of course. Sorry.)

Answer (score 2):

There are two reasons.

One is semantic: the first argument need not be `std::cout`. It can be *any* `std::ostream`, be it `std::cerr`, a `std::ofstream`, a `std::ostringstream`, etc.

The second is syntactic: `<<` necessarily takes two arguments, and there's no way to write an overload without two arguments (though the first argument can be a `this` argument).